# Java to Node.js Conversion of AES and RSA Encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes, rsa

I'm working with an application (Jobvite) that requires me to encrypt data that is sent to its API. Specific steps involve generating a random AES key, using it to encrypt a JSON message, then using a RSA public key to encrypt the AES key, and then send both the encrypted message and the encrypted AES key to the API endpoint (in a JSON object).

I have an example for doing this using Java that works as expected (the code generates the encrypted message + key, which I then post to the API endpoint using Postman, and I get back a successful response). I have implemented a Node.js version of that code. But when I post the encrypted message + key generated by this code to the API endpoint, it returns an error. I verified using online tools that the encrypted message and key produced by the Node.js code do get decrypted successfully, so it seems like the issue might be with the format, or padding, etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**JAVA**

```
String public_key_string = "MIIBIjANBgk************BEtWbhxQIvd4QIDAQAB";

String message = "{\"filter\":{\"process\":{\"DateCreated\":{\"gte\":\"2023-10-01T10:50:00Z\",\"lte\":\"2024-01-31T10:50:00Z\"}}}}";

KeyGenerator key_generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
key_generator.init(256);
SecretKey aes_key = key_generator.generateKey();
byte[] aes_key_byte_array = aes_key.getEncoded();
SecretKey secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(aes_key_byte_array, "AES");

byte[] pub_key_byte_array = Base64.getDecoder().decode(public_key_string);
EncodedKeySpec encoded_key_spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pub_key_byte_array);
PublicKey public_key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(encoded_key_spec);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(1, public_key);
byte[] encrypted_key_bytes = cipher.doFinal(secret_key.getEncoded());
String encrypted_key = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted_key_bytes);

Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher2.init(1, secret_key);
byte[] cipher_bytes = cipher2.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String encrypted_message = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher_bytes);

System.out.println(encrypted_message);
System.out.println(encrypted_key);
```

**Node.js**

```
const public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgk*****BEtWbhxQIvd\n4QIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"

const message = JSON.stringify({"filter":{"process":{"DateCreated":{"gte":"2023-10-01T10:50:00Z","lte":"2024-01-31T10:50:00Z"}}}});

const aes_key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const encrypted_key = crypto.publicEncrypt({"key": public_key, "padding": crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING}, aes_key).toString("base64");

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-ecb", Buffer.from(aes_key), null);
let encrypted_message = cipher.update(message, "utf8", "base64");
encrypted_message += cipher.final("base64");

console.log(encrypted_message);
console.log(encrypted_key);
```

Comment: The codes are equivalent, i.e. the ciphertexts of both codes can be decrypted with *the same* decryption code. The problem must be somewhere else (inconsistent keys, concatenation bug, etc.).

Comment: If you cannot solve the problem, post complete non-productive test data: An RSA key pair (i.e. public *and* private key, PEM encoded, see e.g. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Generate_RSA_Key_Pair('2048','PEM'))) and the ciphertexts of both codes generated with the public key of that key pair.